# Ag-grid React Multiple Selection with Checkbox not getting selection change with Api

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, selection, ag-grid

I want to basically know if I am having rows selected to activate an input, the thing is
"selectionChange" **event is not capturing when the selection is being changed** I have a small example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-react-redux-events-forked-459v6?file=/index.js

What id expect to happen is to **get the alert to show when something is selected on this example**.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in React this property is onSelectionChange, following react pattern